# Is Else or More correct here to use

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

> Open an Instant ICICI Bank Savings Account with your AADHAAR card

I said

> What else document do you require to open a new Savings Account?

Which one is correct to use More or Else or both incorrect?

Comment: both are wrong - 'what other documents ...' is correct

Comment: Why is it wrong?

Comment: else and more are not selectors available to 'documents'

Answer (score 1):

**Else** is an adverb; not an adjective. In the sentence *"What else document..."*, it is used as an adjective qualifying *document* and it is a wrong usage. Instead, you may rephrase it as:
*What other documents are required...?
What else do you require apart from the Aadhaar Card...? What other documents do you require...?*

> **Else** can be used in the following ways: (from **[macmillandictionary.com](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/else)**)
>
> after a pronoun such as ***‘something’, ‘nothing’, ‘anyone’, or
>   ‘everyone’:***
>
> *He married someone else.*
>
> *Is there anything else you wanted?*
>
> after the adverbs ***‘somewhere’, ‘anywhere’, ‘everywhere’, and
>   ‘nowhere’***:
>
> *You’ll have to sit somewhere else.*
>
> after a word such as ***‘what’, ‘who’, ‘how’, or ‘whatever’***:
>
> *Who else was with you?Where else did you go?*
>
> after ***‘much’*** and ***‘little’***:
>
> *I have little else to offer.*
>
> used for showing that you are referring to other things, people,
>   places etc, apart from the particular ones that you mention or know
>   about
>
> *You mustn’t tell anyone else – it’s a secret between you and me.*
>
> *Before we do anything else, we must sit down and make a list.*
>
> *There isn’t much else to tell you.*
>
> *This could only happen in the United States – nowhere else in the world!*